# jsdoc: how to document properties using bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, properties, documentation, jsdoc

Given this rather silly function, how should documentation be written for "range" param?

```
/**
* @param {number} value
 * @param {Object} range
 * @param {number} range['<']
 * @param {number} range['<=']
 * @param {number} range['>']
 * @param {number} range['>=']
 */
function testIsInRange(value, range) {
    var threshold;

    if ((threshold = range['<'], threshold !== undefined) && !(value < threshold)) {
        fail('Value must be less than ' + threshold);
    }

    if ((threshold = range['<='], threshold !== undefined) && !(value <= threshold)) {
        fail('Value must be less than or equal to ' + threshold);
    }

    if ((threshold = range['>'], threshold !== undefined) && !(value > threshold)) {
        fail('Value must be greater than ' + threshold);
    }

    if ((threshold = range['>='], threshold !== undefined) && !(value >= threshold)) {
        fail('Value must be greater than or equal to ' + threshold);
    }
}
```

Neither dot nor bracket notation seems to work. Property types (Object and number) are recognized, however their names are not.

Answer (score 1):

Types can be specified as complex objects:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} value
 * @param {{'<': number, '<=': number, '>': number, '>=': number}} range
 */
function testIsInRange(value, range) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, destructuring can help, though it'll require renaming the parameters to non-symbolic names:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} value
 * @param {number} lt
 * @param {number} lte
 * @param {number} gt
 * @param {number} gte
 */
function testIsInRange(value, {'<':lt, '<=':lte, '>':gt, '>=':gte}) {
    ...
}
```